# How to consume Spring HATEOAS REST resources containing links to another resources?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have `/studentCourses` endpoint on the server (built with Spring Data REST) which returns the following content:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "studentCourses" : [
      {
        "uid" : "5f23abe9-b24e-4e76-86b0-d539950a0a41",
        "registrationDate" : "7/23/2016",
        "_links" : {
          "self" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/studentCourses/5f23abe9-b24e-4e76-86b0-d539950a0a41"
          },
          "studentCourse" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/studentCourses/5f23abe9-b24e-4e76-86b0-d539950a0a41"
          },
          "course" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/studentCourses/5f23abe9-b24e-4e76-86b0-d539950a0a41/course"
          },
          "student" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/studentCourses/5f23abe9-b24e-4e76-86b0-d539950a0a41/student"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/studentCourses"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/studentCourses"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    ...
  }
}
```

And the following client code:

```
class StudentCourseDTO {

    String uuid;

    String registrationDate;

    StudentDTO student; // contains uuid, firstName, lastName, etc.

    CourseDTO course; // contains uuid, name, etc.

    // getters, setters

}

RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter =
            new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    messageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON));
    return new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(messageConverter));
}

...

Collection<StudentCourseDTO> studentCourses = restTemplate().exchange(
        "http://localhost:8080/studentCourses",
        HttpMethod.GET, null,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<StudentCourseDTO>>() {})
        .getBody().getContent();
```

The problem is that `StudentCourseDTO.student` and `StudentCourseDTO.course` are always `null`, but `StudentCourseDTO.uuid` and `StudentCourseDTO.registrationDate` are retrieved correctly from the server.
Anyone has an idea what I have missed?
I think there must be someway to tell `RestTemplate` to automatically follow the links in the returned content like `student` and `course` in the example above, but I haven't found a way to do this.

Comment: I would advise against automatically following these links. You'll probably want to fetch only the information that you need in order the reduce IO, reduce server load and overall simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Just because there are links that does not mean they are automatically followed.

I would change the `StudentCourseDTO` to:

```
class StudentCourseDTO {

    String uuid;

    String registrationDate;

}
```

And then you would deserialize the response to a

```
PagedResources<Resource<StudentCourseDTO>> studentCourses = restTemplate().exchange(
        "http://localhost:8080/studentCourses",
        HttpMethod.GET, null,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<Resource<StudentCourseDTO>>>() {})
        .getBody().getContent();
```

For each `Resource<StudentCourseDTO>` you can then follow the links for `student`and `course`, e.g. by using the `RestTemplate` to retrieve the resources.

Of course this gives you two additional calls per response item - but the only way to avoid this is to change the service to embed this information in the list resource.